# Stream operator and controlling conversion priority

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have a streaming base class:

```
class Stream
{
   virtual Stream& operator<< ( float num ) = 0;
   virtual Stream& operator<< ( double num ) = 0;
   virtual Stream& operator<< ( bool val ) = 0;
};
```

And then I implement an implementation class:

```
class StreamImpl : public Stream
{
   Stream& operator<< ( float num  ) { ... do stuff ... }
   Stream& operator<< ( double num ) { ... do stuff ... } 
   Stream& operator<< ( bool val   ) { ... do stuff ... }
};
```

Then for new classes I create my non-member stream operator functions:

```
class Blar { };

Stream& operator<< ( Stream& str, const Blar& blar ) { ... do stuff ... }
```

It works all fine and dandy. But I have the problem that in some cases the compiler doesn't know which stream operator to use.

Consider when Blar has a cast operator:

```
class Blar 
{
    operator bool() const {  return false; }
};
```

Now the I try to use the stream:

```
void process( Stream& str )
{
    Blar blar;
    str << blar;
}
```

So here is the problem the compiler does not know if it should cast Blar to bool, and then use the Stream member, or cast str to type Stream, and use the non-member stream operator.

Is there a way to prioritize the casts?

Comment: Make the `operator bool()` function `explicit`.

Comment: Good answer - and it would work - but in this case I still want the implicit conversion to work. I'd just like it to be lower priority.

Comment: That should work. Maybe it's a problem with your compiler. See it working at http://ideone.com/GoHnd8. It also works under cygwin/g++ 4.9.3.

Comment: I'm sure it does. But if I add explicit, then I have to cast manually every time I want the cast to happen right? I have write "bool b = (bool)blar;", right?

Comment: Right. I'm looking for a solution where "bool b = blar;" would still work.

Comment: You might have to pay the price of that extra explicit cast to make your program do the right thing if your compiler is not up to the standards.

Comment: @Rafael Have you tried my answer? It may not be bad after all.

Answer (score 0):

This template and SFINAE thing would hopefully remove the ambiguity (by defining `operator<<` for each class derived from `Stream`, which removes the implicit conversion on the left side of `str << blar`):

```
// the following operator could potentially be defined in the template below, I'm just extending your code
Stream& operator<< (Stream& str, const Blar& blar) { /* something */ return str; }

template <
    typename Str,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<Stream, Str>::value &&
        !std::is_same<Stream, Str>::value
    >::type
>
Stream& operator<< (Str& str, const Blar& blar) { return static_cast<Stream&>(str) << blar; }
```

But, even to me, it looks just like an extra mess, and it requires reviewing - maybe @R Sahu would be kind to do that?